# A Sample of Tritium-3 Decayed to 94.5% of its Original Amount After a Year. (a) What is the half-life of tritium-3?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Please use the following notation when explaining the solution.

The formula I am aware of is $P(t)=P_oe^{kt}$

$P_o=\ initial\ amount$

t = time

k = growth rate

(a) What is the half-life of tritium-3?

How would I calculate?

(b) How long would it take the sample to decay to 20% of its original amount?

> Please keep in mind I am looking for clear and suitable methods a 2nd
>   semester Calculus student can use to solve problems such as this.

Comment: Half life is the time when $P(t) = P_0 / 2$. You're solving for this time. (b) is the time when $P(t) = 0.2 P_0$. Again, you're solving for this value of $t$. This doesn't require calculus.

Comment: This is Calculus. It is a question from a Calculus book. Why the down votes?

Comment: Put your thoughts and effort into the question! @SunnyBlack

Comment: Where the question was asked is immaterial. The techniques required to solve these equations are algebra and logarithms, which are covered in pre-calculus. I didn't down vote, but I suspect the down votes are not because you because you mislabeled the topic, but probably because you asked a standard question, and provided no indication that you made any attempt yourself.

Comment: @Gooby I have. I am trying to seek methods which I can remember and make sense to me.

Comment: Ok Chester - good enough. However, I already have the answer and a method, but the method seems very convoluted and inelegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, $$P(t)=P_{0}e^{kt}$$ Where, growth rate $$k=-\lambda=-\frac{\ln 2}{t_{1/2}}$$ Since, the amount after time $t=1\ year$ decays to $P(t)=94.5$ % of initial value $P_0$, hence substituting the corresponding values in the formula as follows  $$\frac{94.5}{100}P_0=P_0e^{-\lambda \times 1}$$ $$e^{-\lambda}=0.945$$ $$\lambda=-\ln(0.945)$$ Hence the half life of tritium-3 is given $$t_{1/2}=\frac{\ln 2}{-\ln(0.945)}=12.25\ \text{years}$$

Now, the time $t$ taken by the sample to decay to $20$ % of original amount hence,
$$\frac{20}{100}P_0=P_0e^{-\lambda t}$$ $$e^{-\lambda t}=0.2$$ $$-\lambda t=\ln(0.2)$$ $$t=\frac{\ln(0.2)}{\ln(0.945)}=28.45 \ \text{years}$$

Comment: Could someone please explain the reason for what is wrong in the answer?

Comment: I am bit confused when it comes to your method (I did not down vote you by the way) . Any way we are multiplying the 94.5% by the initial amount. Yet from that point I really cannot follow what you are doing? Also, I would prefer if you used regular variables and not Greek letters. Your answer is right. However, you are doing a poor job showing me how you arrived at it.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot I do not see any thing wrong in your answer. I did this problem myself and got the same result! However there is some work in your answer that might not be clear to a person just learning these things.